# what is the right xpath function for exclude the node

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

i have a problem with xpath function

I want to get "First Row" and "Fourth Row" only but i want to get it with logic which has statement,

First statement is i want to get with node which has a class "row1"
Second, i want to ignore all node which has a class "excludeRow"

I have tried not(starts-with) and not(contains(@class, "excludeRow")) function but still cannot get what i want.

This one is my example case

```
<tr><td>"Header"</td></tr>
<tr class="row1"><td>"First Row"</td><tr>
<tr class="excludeRow1"><td>"Second Row"</td></tr>
<tr class="excludeRow2"><td>"Third Row"</td></tr>
<tr><td>"Fourth Row"</td></tr>
<tr class="excludeRow3"><td>"Fifth Row"</td></tr>
```

This one is my recent code, hopefully someone can correct or solve this :D

1. '//tr[@class="row1" and not(starts-with(@class, 'excludeRow'))]';
2. '//tr[not(contains(@class, 'excludeRow'))]';

there is no error on this code but the result is not as i expected

Thanks everybody, Regards ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've used `or` to select row that, *either* has `class` attribute equals 'row1' *or* doesn't have `class` attribute starting with 'excludeRow'. However, this will include the "Header" row. If you want to skip "Header", add another condition to skip first `tr` :

```
//tr[position() > 1][@class='row1' or not(starts-with(@class, 'excludeRow'))]
```

The above XPath should returns the two expected rows "First Row" and "Fourth Row" (see demo in [xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9558a8080bf57bd876d93baf546ef7ef))

Comment: thanks man for solving my problem  ! :D 
i did not know there are xpathtester online too :D

Comment: @HaryonoSariputra Sama-sama bro :D Yup, that xpath tester would help a lot on testing your XPath independently

Answer (score 0):

First of all, beware that you are using invalid html as your second row is not closed properly. But if it is closed properly, the following statements should work:

1. `//tr[@class="row1"]`
2. `//tr[not(contains(@class, "excludeRow")) and not(@class="row1") and not(position()=1)]`

The first statement simply selects all tr with a class equal to `row1`.

The second statement selects all tr that do not contain excludeRow inside their class attribute and in addition exludes the rows selected in the first statement. In the end to exclude the header row, it excludes the first element.